# How can call instance by COM?

Tags: com, f#, windows-xp, skype

I try to call skype instance by COM on F#.
A aim is get mood message.

#### test.fs

```
// Import skype4com Api
open SKYPE4COMLib

type SKYPE4COM =
    new() = new SKYPE4COM()

let GetMood =
    let aSkype = new SKYPE4COM
    mood <- aSkype.CurrentUserProfile.MoodText
    mood
```

But when build(before too),error occur.

> Incomplete structured construct at or before this point in expression

Thanks in advance.

this is next version what I think.

#### test01.fs

```
// Import skype4com Api
open SKYPE4COMLib

let GetMood =
    let aSkype = new SKYPE4COMLib()              // line 1
    mood <- aSkype.CurrentUserProfile.MoodText   // line 2
    mood                                         // line 3
```

error message(when building).
line in 1:error FS0039: The type 'SKYPE4COMLib' is not defined
line in 2:error FS0039: The value or constructor 'mood' is not defined
line in 3:error FS0039: The value or constructor 'mood' is not defined

also like that...

Comment: The message is a general syntax/formatting problem.  Which line is it indicating? -- the problem will be in the expression before that.

Comment: thanks comment. message in this line 'mood <- aSkype.CurrentUserProfile.MoodText'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has several issues.  First of all, your constructor for the `SKYPE4COM` class appears to be recursive (?!), which is going to cause a stack overflow if you try to create an instance.  Secondly, the error that you're receiving is because you are using the `new` operator, but you haven't completed the call to the constructor (i.e. you need to apply the constructor using parentheses: `let aSkype = new SKYPE4COM()`).  Even then, though, you've got another issue because your type doesn't expose a `CurrentUserProfile` property, so your code still won't work.

Try something like this:

```
open SKYPE4COMLib

let getMood() =
  SkypeClass().CurrentUserProfile.MoodText
```

Comment: thanks advice. But still I wonder that why need to expose CurrentUserProfile property. Because I think for example open System.Windows.Forms then let frm = new Form();frm.Text <- "foo". That works,even no define type and property... (at entry I did not add open SKYPE4COMLib)    
by the way I don't make that instance in recursive.

Comment: thank you very much. let getMood = SkypeClass().CurrentUserProfile.MoodText. then completely works as I want. appreciate!

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a [Type Extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233211%28VS.100%29.aspx) to add a member to an already existing type:

```
open SKYPE4COMLib

type SKYPE4COMLib with
    member this.GetMood() =
        aSkype.CurrentUserProfile.MoodText
```

This would allow you to access GetMood as if it were a member function defined on the SKYPE4COMLib type:

```
let x = new SKYPE4COMLib()
printfn "%A" (x.GetMood())
```