# How to create an instance of skype class in c#?

Tags: c#, com, skype, skype4com

I'm trying to make use of `SKYPE4COMLib.dll`.

I've got past referencing the library (huh), and now I'm trying to create an instance of skype:

```
Skype s=new SkypeClass();
```

I'm getting following errors:

```
The type 'SKYPE4COMLib.SkypeClass' has no constructors defined
```

and

```
Interop type 'SKYPE4COMLib.SkypeClass' cannot be embedded. Use the applicable interface instead.
```

The samples I've seen are in VB, and they use

```
Set oSkype = WScript.CreateObject("Skype4COM.Skype", "Skype_")
```

which I don't know how to translate.

Also, I've found [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1929690/how-can-call-instance-by-com), which seems related, but the answer doesn't seem to be applicable to c#.

How do I create the Skype class in c#?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quite simply it is just

```
Skype skype = new Skype();
```

Even though `Skype` is technically a interface you can still call `new` on it due to it being a COM interface, that is how C# com interop works.

The way to tell is by going to the "go to definition" tab for the Skype class, it should look like this.

```
[CoClass(typeof(SkypeClass))]
[Guid("B1878BFE-53D3-402E-8C86-190B19AF70D5")]
public interface Skype : ISkype, _ISkypeEvents_Event
{
}
```

That `CoClass(typeof(SkypeClass))` is what lets you call `new` on the interface.

Comment: hehe. apparently resharper's auto suggest didn't know about that )

Answer (score 2):

```
var skype= Activator.CreateInstance( 
Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Skype4COM.Skype")) as ISkype;
```